# Zero Score for Up-Votes

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I'm seeing odd behavior on SO.  The last two upvotes I've received have been for a score of zero.  For instance, Post1 I just got an upvote of 1, and Post2 I just got an upvote of 1 as well.  My score did not reflect, and in the drop-down summary of my username at the top of SO it shows those two posts but with a score of `0` to the left.

Is there a reason for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit your rep cap.  The cap is 200, doesn't count accepts.  You have 260, 60 of which is accepts, leaving 200 from upvotes.

Congrats on hitting it btw

Comment: Wow, I did not know that!  Very interesting.  What happens to the non-counted upvotes?  Do they just disappear, or do they perchance roll forward for the next day or something?  I'm guessing the former, but figured I'd ask anyways.

Comment: If they would roll to the next day, Jon Skeet would likely hit the rep cap daily for 2 years without posting anything. No, this won't happen ;) By the way, based on your reputation history, you've hit it at least twice before.

Answer (score 2):

It can be 1 of 2 things:

1. your answer is (has become) Community Wiki
2. you have passes the 200 rep limit for today

A quick look at your SO account shows it is 2)